# Recuperar nome das tabelas mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Gostaria de recuperar o nome das minhas tabelas em java com banco mysql. Não sei se está correto eu recebo uma hashcode: (1) model.Campanhas@b5cca49 (2) model.Campanhas@5c369e04

```
 public ArrayList<Object>  nameTables(){
    try {
        String SQL = "SHOW tables";
        PreparedStatement ps = dataSource.getConexao().prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("TABELAS CONSULTADAS COM SUCESSO");
        ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()){
           Pedidos pedidos = new Pedidos();
           pedidos.setNomePedidos(rs);
           lista.add(pedidos);
        }
        rs.close();
        return lista;
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERRO AO PESQUISAR TABELAS: "+ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.err.println("ERRO GERAL AO PESQUISAR TABELA: "+ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao escrever a lista você está exibindo a referência ao ResultSet, não o nome da tabela, porque no trecho `pedidos.setNomePedidos(rs);` você está passando por parâmetro todo o objeto. Para funcionar, você deve fazer `pedidos.setNomePedidos(rs.getString(1));`.

Para entender melhor o comando getString, acesse a documentação do java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)

Comment: Obrigado, graças a sua resposta consegui a solução. já que outras coisas também estavam errados. Ai quando eu coloquei o que você falou já acusou o erro. Ai só fui consertando.  Vlw mesmo.